# Display all model fields in template

Tags: django

I am trying to display all the fields of a model called company as a list in my template. But can't seem to make it work.

**Code**

```
<ul>
    {% for field in company.fields.all %}
  <li>{{ fields.name }}</li>

    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get list of fields with

```
company._meta.get_fields()
```

But you can not access `_meta` attribute in template, because it starts with `_`. So, you can assign _meta or result of get_fields() to variable with legal name in view, or return list of fields from your custom template filter.
Example with view:

```
return render(request, 'your_template.html', {
    'company': company, 
    'company_fields': company._meta.get_fields()
})
```

and in template:

```
{% for field in company_fields %}
    {{ field.att_name }}
{% endfor %}
```